# The current standard to replicate static content in html and php

Tags: php, html, static

I understand that `<?php include 'filename.php';?>` can be used to replicate static content across multiple pages.

I have done this for some previous sites before, however I am trying to make a more professional website and I'm not sure that dotting around lots of  `<?php include` is such a good way to go, it feels like glue.

Is this how the professionals are doing it? I ask this because all my pages end up having a `include` for the title, the header, the footer and the navigation.

If there is no better or cleaner way I will continue, but if there is a better way people are managing this I would like to know.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of professionals use templating libraries. It's a more object oriented way of doing what you are talking about. The idea is that you can break content down into even smaller reusable pieces along with a few methods for adding dynamic content, and then it's really pretty simple to construct a web page.

Consider making a php class like the following, if you want to roll your own:

```
<?php

class Link
{
public $relation;
public $type;
public $href;

public function __construct($relation, $type, $href)
{
    $this->relation = $relation;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->href = $href;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<link rel='$this->relation' type='$this->type' href='$this->href'>";
}
}

class Anchor
{
public $href;
public $content;

public function __construct($href, $content)
{
    $this->href = $href;
    $this->content = $content;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<a href='$this->href'>$this->content</a>";
}
}

class Script
{
public $source;
public $type;

public function __construct($source, $type)
{
    $this->source = $source;
    $this->type = $type;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<script src='$this->source' type='$this->type'></script>";
}
}

class Option
{
public $value;
public $text;

public function __construct($value, $text)
{
    $this->value = $value;
    $this->text = $text;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<option value='$this->value'>$this->text</option>";
}
}

class Select
{
public $options;
public $name;

public function __construct($name, $options)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->options = $options;
}   

public function __toString()
{
    $result = "<select id='$this->name'>";
    foreach($this->options as $option)
        $result.=$option;
    $result.= "</select>";
    return $result;
}
}

class Div
{
public $id;
public $class;
public $content;

public function __construct($id, $class, $content)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->class = $class;
    $this->content = $content;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<div id='$this->id' class='$this->class'>$this->content</div>";
}
}


class HeaderItem
{
public $title;
public $links;

public function __construct($title, $links)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->links = $links;  
}

public function __toString()
{
    $result = "<head>"."<title>$this->title</title>";
    foreach($this->links as $link)
        $result.= $link;
    $result.= "</head>";
    return $result;
}
}

class Document
{
public $header;
public $body;

public function __construct($header, $body)
{
    $this->header = $header;
    $this->body = $body;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return "<!DOCTYPE HTML>$this->header<html><body>$this->body</body></html>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put this class? If it's going to be used by many pages, does the php go in a special file in the website root?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want I suppose, though personally I like to make a templating directory and call this particular file template_engine.php, then I will usually make a base_template.php for my whole site that contains the basic structure. I will then include both the template_engine, and base_template on the pages I'm using - then just add the few custom elements that make them different from other pages and you're good to go. usually an include will look like this: `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templating/templating_engine.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MVC programming.

Includes are generally how you include a header or footer etc to your document. But in big projects you would normally make a class that includes a header, and any dynamic information. It would then return the parsed result.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

As @AdamTester suggested, MVC (Model, View, Controller) is definitely the way to go. You use your models to handle the data - load it from the database etc or whatever you want to do. The controllers allow you to do whatever you need to do and output the resulting content using a view. You can easily achieve what you are looking to do with [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

I would certainly suggest using Smarty or a similar templating engine to handle your views as you can also segment the different views in an ordered manner.